# Tomcat / handling connections when use NIO mode

Tags: multithreading, tomcat, websocket

I have a web socket server which is runnnig on Tomcat.

Tomcat works in NIO – non-blocking I/O (many more connections than threads) mode.

maxConnections = 1000
  maxThreads = 200

Assuming 300 connections for example , all 300 users can be serve simultaneously by Tomcat ??

I mean, one thred from pool can switch between 2 ore more connections because of 300 > 200 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Tomcat *can* manage more connections than requests currently in-flight (meaning, work is actively being done on those requests), the in-flight requests are limited by the number of request-processing threads.

So if you have 200 threads, you can only work on 200 requests at a time. The other 300 requests will sit in a queue until a request-processing thread is available.

This The above situation is the case for "normal" requests using standard HTTP request-response.

If you switch into asynchronous mode, things change. If you upgrade the connection to Websocket, things also change. But those are completely different I/O and dispatch models where the term "request" sort of loses its original meaning.

I believe that Tomcat allocates a single thread *per connection* for an upgraded Websocket connection, and that thread will handle the connection and no others. So when upgrading to Websocket, you are turning Tomcat's request-dispatch model from one thread-per-request into one thread-per-connection.

Answer (score 0):

All the websocket connections was kept in "maxConnections", and a message would trigger a thread in "maxThreads" to handle it. If a thread is dealing with a message, and a new message comes from the same websocket, the new message will waits to be handled.

So a tomcat instance can keeps 10000 websockets by default.